# Adding data to arrays in C

Tags: c, linux, arrays, string

I have a few arrays that I wanted to update. The problem is that when data is added to the array, some variables are updated to 0.

my code to add data:

```
void addStockItem(){
    system(CLS_NAME);
    printf("New Item\n\n");
    printf("New Item Name   : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",&*itemName[totalItem]);
    //itemName[totalItem][30] = strupr(itemName[totalItem]);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("New Item Price  : ");
    scanf("%f",&item_Price_Profit[totalItem][0]);
    printf("New Item Profit : ");   
    scanf("%f",&item_Price_Profit[i][1]);
    printf("New Item Qty    : ");   
    scanf("%d",&itemQuantity[totalItem][0]);
    itemQuantity[totalItem][1]=0;
    itemQuantity[totalItem][2]=0;
    ++totalItem;
    allStocks();
}
```

the data,

```
int totalItem=13,itemQuantity[][3]={8,0,0,9,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,22,0,\
  0,16,0,0,18,0,0,9,0,0,7,0,0,5,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0},sessionQuantity;

float item_Price_Profit[][2]={1,0.5,2,0.2,3,0.2,4,0.2,5,0.5,6,0.8,7,0.5,8,0.2,9,\
0.2,10,0.2,11,0.5,12,0.8,13,0.9};

char itemName[][30]={"STABILO PENCIL 2B","STABILO PEN 0.5",\
"STABILO ERASER","STABILO RULER","STABILO TEST PAD","STABILO BOOK","STABILO SCISSORS","STABILO SHARPENER","STABILO GLUE","STABILO CHALK","STABILO MARKER PEN","OXFORD DICTIONARY","STABILO HIGHLIGHTER"};
```

full code: http://pastebin.com/jjuCCrjz

[EDIT]
Everything work as they intended to after I changed itemQuantity[][3] to itemQuantity[100][3], item_Price_Profit[][2] to item_Price_Profit[100][2] and itemName[][30] to itemName[100][30]. What could possibly my mistake other than scanf?

Comment: please don't use `scanf()` it is harmful, and dangerous even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't access pastebin from my work computer, so I'll have to go by what's posted.

Several issues off the bat:

1. `fflush` is only defined to work on output streams, not input streams; the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined* (it will do *something*, but probably not what you want).  If you need to clear out garbage from the input stream, you'll need to consume it using `getchar()` or `fgets()` or similar until you see a newline or some other indicator that you've cleared out the garbage.  The `%f` and `%d` conversion specifiers will skip over any leading whitespace, and by having the blank before the `%[` conversion specifier will also cause any leading whitespace to be skipped.  So ditch the `fflush` calls altogether.
2. `scanf(" %[^\n]s",&*itemName[totalItem]);` - this looks confused.  Unless you expect the input to always have a trailing `s` character, the conversion specifier should simply be `%[^\n]`.  The `&*` in front of `itemName` is redundant; you just need to write

   ```
   scanf(" %[^\n]", itemName[totalItem]);
   ```

   Although you should probably put a field width specifier in there:

   ```
   scanf(" %30[^\n]", itemName[titalItem]);
   ```

   to avoid buffer overflow.
3. You're accessing all your data items (`totalItem`, `itemName`, `item_Price_Profit`, etc.) as global variables.  This is usually a recipe for heartburn.  Ideally, functions and their callers should not share state via globals; rather, they should communicate through parameters, return values, and exceptions (where supported).  Something more like

   ```
    void addStockItem(char *name, float *price, float *profit, float *quantity)
    {
      ...
      scanf(" %30[^\n]", name);
      ...
      scanf("%f", price);
      ...
      scanf("%f", profit);
      ...
      scanf("%d", quantity); 
    }
   ```

   which would be called like

   ```
    addStockItem(itemName[totalItem], 
                 &item_Price_Profit[totalItem][0], 
                 &item_Price_Profit[i][1], 
                 &itemQuantity[totalItem][0]);
   ```
4. Your data structures feel really hinky to me, but that's likely because I can't see your entire program.

Comment: Thanks for answering and clearing things up. I'll consider removing fflush(stdin).. I followed #2, the scanf works great, but appending the data to the array's new row causes segmentation error(segmentation error occur after appending the data). For #3, the arrays are being used in many functions. So passing it around could be very confusing, at least for me. I have very little experience in programming.

Comment: @hudadiaz: *"I'll consider removing fflush(stdin)"* - There's nothing to consider; you are invoking undefined behavior with that call an it is wrong in all circumstances.

Comment: @Ed I've removed it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s",&*itemName[totalItem]);
```

can't be right. This is passing a character converted to a pointer, where `scanf()` expects a pointer to character. You probably mean:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", itemName[totalItem]);
```